# Switching 9V using a NPN transistor and 5V alarm output

Tags: transistors, relay, npn

I am needing to trigger a relay with the alarm output of a fluke DAQ. The alarm is only outputting 5V 0.15mA which is not enough current to trigger the relay I am using, a Data Loggers IoT Relay II.

I am wanting to use a NPN transistor to trigger the relay with the alarm output, but am having trouble getting it to work. I have attached a diagram of the circuit I am using, and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image: cicruit]

Comment: Does the relay need 9 V? Why are Relay_neg and Relay_pos connected in your schematic? This will just short the 9 V power supply. I assume the relay coil should be there between those points. Also, don't forget to add a flyback diode. You circuit should look like [the one in this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28201).

Comment: @StarCat it doesn't necessarily need to be 9V, I had a 9V power supply on hand. I am using an adjustable power supply to test the circuit, so I could use another voltage. Connecting the relay was unintentional, but I will look into a flyback diode and that other thread. Thank you.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Yes, there should be a flyback diode to avoid possible damage to the transistor when it turns off. But if that was your *only* problem you'd expect it to work at least once and probably many times.

Comment: @user253751 i ended up getting it to work using a darlington pair. would a flyback diode still be necessary?

Comment: A flyback diode should always be used. I'm not sure if it's "necessary", but it's a good idea. The only way to know whether it was necessary is when you don't have one and the transistor breaks after some days or weeks or months